# How to fix: "All the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly" python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, correlation

I save the loop results in an array but I get the error:

> all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

The code is:

```py
r = 24
sp = np.zeros(r)
p = np.zeros(r)
for t in range(r):
    sp[t], p[t] = scipy.stats.spearmanr((df1['Pasto_1'][t:]), (df1['HumedadPasto_1'][:-t]))
```

I expect the output saved in `s` and `p`. If you know what I am doing wrong, thank you very much!

Comment: You don't tell us anything about `df1`.  From the name I suspect it's a `pandas` dataframe.  And you haven't shown us the full error.  The error talks about `concatenation`, which must be occurring inside the `spearmanr` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is most likely with the first iteration: When `t` is 0, `df1['Pasto_1'][t:]` is the full series, but `df1['HumedadPasto_1'][:-t]` is empty. You could simply treat 0 as a special case and be good:

```py
for t in range(r):
    s1 = df1['Pasto_1'][t:]
    s2 = df1['HumedadPasto_1'][:-t] if t > 0 else df1['HumedadPasto_1']
    sp[t], p[t] = scipy.stats.spearmanr(s1, s2)
```